# mdpf can't create pdf with <b> or <s> tags

Tags: php, css, html-table, pdf-generation

I'm trying to create a pdf out of an html table which is created through php.
I use php version 5.4.7 and mdpf version  5.7.3.

This code does not work:

```
<?php

 include('../../mpdf/mpdf.php');


$mpdf=new mPDF('utf-8', 'A4-L');
$test2 = "<table class='timon' border='1'>
              <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th>Montag</th>
                    <th>Dienstag</th>
                    <th>Mittwoch</th>
                    <th>Donnerstag</th>
                    <th>Freitag</th>
                    <th>Avg. Tag</th>
                  </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
              <tr>
              <td>Morgen (0.3) </td>
              <td><s>test user 0.36</s><br /></td>
              <td></td>
              <td><s>test user 0.26</s><br /></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td> </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
              <td>Mittag (0.5) </td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td> </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
              <td>Nachmittag (0.5) </td>
              <td><s>test user 0.16</s><br /></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td><s>test user 0.46</s><br /></td>
              <td> </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
              <td>Ganzer Tag (1) </td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td><s>test user 1.2</s><br /></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td> </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
              <td>Total Auslastung</td>
              <td>0</td>
              <td>0</td>
              <td>0</td>
              <td>0</td>
              <td>0</td>
              <td>0</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
              <td>Total Gruppe</td>
              <td>7.5</td>
              <td>7.5</td>
              <td>7.5</td>
              <td>7.5</td>
              <td>7.5</td>
              <td>7.5</td>
              </tr><tr>
              <td>Freie Plätze</td>
              <td style='background-color:#c6efce;'>7.5</td>
              <td style='background-color:#c6efce;'>7.5</td>
              <td style='background-color:#c6efce;'>7.5</td>
              <td style='background-color:#c6efce;'>7.5</td>
              <td style='background-color:#c6efce;'>7.5</td>
              <td style='background-color:#c6efce;'>7.5</td>
              </tr>
              </tbody>
              </table>";



$mpdf->WriteHTML($test2,2);

$filename = "test.pdf";

$mpdf->Output($filename,'I');
exit;

?>
```

If I remove just one of the < s> tags, the PDF will be created fine. Eg.:

```
              <td><s>test user 0.36</s><br /></td>
              <td>test user 0.36<br /></td>
```

it also have problems with the < b> and < u> tag.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You must close the `<s>` tag. mPDF is very strict with opening and closing tags. And not all of your opening tags are closed.

f.i.

```
         <td><s>test user 0.36<s><br /></td>
```

Is not closed properly.

Comment: Ops i made a mistake during testing, just added the missing / and the result is still the same.

Comment: @Timon Strange, i have coped the html from your question and it is working fine, but that won't help you... I use version 5.7.3.

Answer (score 0):

I found the mistake. I had an additional php include and this php had an body and html tag in it. I just removed it and now it works fine. BR